# print object inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array called *list* into which I am entering several objects. Each item has a unique id and title.

```
var number = 0;
var list = [];
var item = {};
var i;

var compute = {
    number : 0,
    newItem : function (input) {
        for (i = 0; i < list.length + 1; i++) {
            var item = {
                id: number,
                title: input
            };
        }
        number++;
        list.push(item);
    }
};
```

and I'm adding data to the array like so:

```
compute.newItem("Something Important");
compute.newItem("Another thing");
```

I'm trying to print out the contents of this array into an HTML list something like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Something Important</li>
    <li>Another thing</li>
</ul>
```

And so on, with each object being printed into its own list element. I'm not sure how to properly print this though? Any thoughts?

I thought something like this might work but I got errors.

```
var content;
for (i = 0; i < list.length + 1; i++) {
    content += "<li>" + list[i] + "</li>";
}
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = content;
```

The error is: cannot set property 'innerHTML' null

(Note that my javascript may just plain suck...I'm very new to this language.)

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: just seeing in the console would not be enough?

Comment: Each loop iteration, you are creating a new `item` variable.  Then you are throwing all but the last one away.  Why do you have that `for` loop there and why are `number++; list.push(item);` outside of it?

Comment: number is to keep track of the id (it adds one each time so the id is never the same.)

Comment: How are you calling this JavaScript?  You need to call it *after* the "list" element exists.  Either by using `window.onload` or putting the script after the body/element.

Comment: The script is after the body element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var compute = {
    list : [],
    newItem : function (input) {
        this.list.push({
            id : this.list.length,
            title : input
        });
    },
    printList : function (el) {
        var ul;
        ul = el || document.createElement('ul');
        for (i = 0; i < this.list.length; i += 1) {
            ul.innerHTML += '<li>' + this.list[i].title + '</li>';
        }
        return ul;
    }
};

compute.newItem('foo');
compute.newItem('bar');
compute.printList(document.getElementById('list'));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Though I'm not sure what ul = el || document.createElement('ul'); is there for. Is it checking to make sure there is an ul element?

Comment: Because it's more flexible at very little cost. I can pass in an existing list, which will let me append to it, or, if I don't pass one in, I get a new list that I can do whatever I want with.

Comment: When you pass in the list element by its id to the method it won't duplicate it thanks to `ul = el || document.createElement('ul');`. This way you can make sure you are always working with the same `ul` element.